# Library for reading blk00000.dat file either using Python or NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, blockchain

I would like to know if there are any libraries that would be able to read blk00000.dat file. It can be either in Python or NodeJS libraries. Please recommend me some of the ones that you guys think is useful for working with blockchain.

Comment: That file is part of a large set of files in a BDB database (which can be read with a library for Berkeley DB files). Trying to read it individually is pointless, and you may want to consider a higher level blockchain API anyway (since the database is an implementation detail of the specific blockchain client you're using)

Comment: What block-chain API would you recommend?

Comment: It depends. Which of many blockchains are you looking to interact with? The use of BDB files strongly hints at the use of one of the bitcoin (and forks thereof) clients; you can just use its RPCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Python**, `bssdb`, now deprecated, or the unofficial port for Python3, `bssdb3`, seem to be the only libraries for Berkeley DB in Python.
For **NodeJS** it seems the library for it is simply called `berkeleydb`

Also please note this is an **off-topic** post

Comment: @devaaron Except tool and library recommendations are explicitly off-topic on this site. It's not a very suitable question (in the way that technical, precisely answerable ones are)